# Present tense or Will

Tags: present-tense, future-tense, future-time

> The person who wins gets the prize
>
> The person who wins **will** get the prize
>
> The person who **will** win gets the prize
>
> The person who **will** win **will** get the prize

Which of the above are correct please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two are both normal. English doesn't really have a future tense: the modal expression "will win" is often used with future meaning, but if the futurity is already clear, then the "present simple" can be used just as well.

The second two are less common: I can't think of any circumstances where they are likely to be used.

The expression "the person who will win", I think will only be used to identify the person, not to say something about them (and it's unlikely, because it is making a prediction). So "The person who will win is my brother" is grammatical, and normal (but only if it is already clear who will win).

Comment: Thank you very much kind sir!